# MDB unable to connect Foreign Server destination in Weblogic 12c Cluster

Tags: jms, cluster-computing, weblogic12c

I have deployed EAR in Weblogic 12c server targeting a cluster. Here cluster comprises of 2 managed servers on same physical machine.

Now, as per my requirement the application consumes messages from foreign destination e.g. MQ Series, so I have an MDB in my application that should make connection to remote queue via JNDI lookup.

So, in order to fulfill this, I have perfomed following steps:

1) Created a JMS server which targets to cluster.

2) Created a JMS Module which targets to cluster.

3) Inside JMS module created a Foreign server and checked on option - "Default Targeting Enabled". So, it is also targetting to cluster same as its parent.

4) Inside Foreign server, I have created destination and connection factories.

After making above changes, when I tried to deploy my EAR, I am getting following error messages. My MDB is not making connection to destination message queue.

**The Message-Driven EJB TestMDB is unable to connect to the JMS destination jms/TEST_FEED_QUEUE. The Error was:
The destination for the MessageDrivenBean TESTMDB could not be resolved at this time. Please ensure the destination is  available at the JNDI name jms/TEST_FEED_QUEUE.  The EJB container will periodically attempt to resolve this MessageDrivenBean destination and additional warnings may be issued.**

Similar errors were displayed on other managed server as well.

Please suggest, where I am doing wrong. Please suggest.